# Mining Bitcoin on Linux with CUDA?

Tags: linux, gpu

I have a Linux machine with an Nvidia GPU (*GeForce GTX 760*). Is there a tool, rather than writing your own, that can currently mine Bitcoin using CUDA on Linux?

Answer (score 4):

There is a program called CudaMiner that can be compiled to run on Linux.

https://github.com/cbuchner1/CudaMiner/

I've also written some more notes about compiling CudaMiner here
http://www.fractured-state.com/2014/03/scrypt-mining-on-aws-nvidia-gpu-with-cudaminer/

UPDATE:

The second link is dead already, but a similar tutorial is detailed in this thread:
https://www.reddit.com/r/dogemining/comments/1y3ygr/dogecoin_guide_for_mining_on_linux_ubuntumint/

Comment: This link may be helpful (I added it without an stackechange account, but it does not appear) https://www.reddit.com/r/dogemining/comments/1y3ygr/dogecoin_guide_for_mining_on_linux_ubuntumint/